# How to pull/retrieve data directly to the external directory from remote instead of creating local copies using DVC?

Tags: git, version-control, dvc

I'm currently working on a project where I want to **push/version data from an external location to a remote storage** using DVC, and subsequently **pull/retrieve updates from the remote repository back to the external location**. In this process, I intend to **keep only the `.dvc` files in the local workspace**.

To provide more context, here are the specific requirements:

- **Tracking an External Dataset**: I have an external dataset located at `/external-to-workspace/dataset`, and I want to track this dataset using DVC.
- **Uploading Dataset Versions to DVC Remote**: I need to upload different versions of the dataset to a DVC remote using ssh, which is located at `ssh://example.com/path/to/storage`.
- **Updating the External Dataset from DVC Remote**: Instead of creating a local copy of the dataset when pulling/retrieving from the remote, I want to update the external dataset itself. This means that the changes made to the dataset in the DVC remote should be reflected in the original external location.

I tried `dvc import-url --to-remote` which copies data from the external to remote but `dvc pull` creates local copies instead of pulling to the external directiory again.

I believe DVC provides the necessary functionalities to accomplish this, but I am unsure about the exact steps and configuration required. If anyone has experience with a similar setup or any suggestions on how to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

How about this option. In the `/external-to-workspace/` initialize a DVC and Git repository of its own. In it you could use all the regular commands like `dvc add`, `dvc push`, etc to  version your data and save it to remote. The data location stays the same `/external-to-workspace/dataset`, you would just have an extra `/external-to-workspace/.dvc` an `/external-to-workspace/.git`. To avoid data duplication make sure that symlinks are enabled.

In the project repository in turn, you will have two options.

1. Use the data in the external repo directly, don't use DVC in it at all.
2. Use `dvc import` (+setup DVC in a way that it shares the cache with the external repo, so that we don't move data around).

Does it sound reasonable as a approach? (I can give more specific commands on how to try it).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As this is a collaborative project, we have adopted a more straightforward approach similar to what you mentioned in the first part. The data owner has initiated a GitHub repo (along with DVC) in his/her local machine and only using that to push them remotely. The remaining users are also maintaining their own repo to pull the data to their workspace. As everything is happening in a single Unbunut server, there are some data duplications in each of the users' repo but still, it is giving them to flexibility to decide on their data version, which is the beauty of DVC.